# PHP SSH execute gnome-calculator (ubuntu)

Tags: php, ssh, graphic

Hi im using php and ssh and want to execute a graphic programm like gnome-calculator. How can i do this? This is my code:

```
    <?php
   if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
// log in at server1.example.com on port 22
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("localhost", 22))){
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
    // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "terminator", "root")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        // allright, we're in!
        echo "okay: logged in...\n";
    $get = $_GET['cmd'];
        // execute a command
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, $get ))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } 
    else {
            // collect returning data from command
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while($line = fgets($stream)) {
    echo nl2br($line);
}

            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
?>
`
```

I can do commands like ls -a or mkdir etc. But i cant get something like an app to execute a graphic interface (like executing gnome-calculator) How would i do this? I use my code like this: http://localhost/index.php?cmd=ls%20-a

Just fooling arround!

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is impossible but it is not so simple like you're coding.
Have a look at [HTML client for X11 ssh forwarding?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104345)

Comment: Are you trying to get the calculator to run on another TTY?  If so see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170075/88823

Comment: how would i use this for setsid for gnome calc?

Answer (score 1):

And you expect it will pop up X-window application from inside of web browser? This is NOT possible from the concept of HTTP and X11 applications.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Abdulla I don't think this is another question. It is an answer, with the message that what the OP originally wanted to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. PHP is executed on the server **before** any data is passed back to the client's machine. If you try to execute any application, it will run on the server as the user you specify (or the web server's user if none is set), the results interpreted on the server (if they are captured) which would then have to be presented to the client on the web page.

To run an external program on the client's machine, you would need to use some other system where the language runs on the client's machine. Whether such a system exists is open to further discussion (in other words, I don't know so I'm not going to dig a hole for myself)

The obvious problem you need to take into account is this: what do you do if the client's machine doesn't have the app installed and available?